# C - list all files in current directory then move in directory above, list files, and so on until root directory is reached

Tags: c, linux

Could you help me please to develop a program in C that scans the current directory and
displays the names of all files that are located there
with extensions. Then program goes to
parent directory, which then becomes current, and these
above steps are repeated until the current directory is not
become root directory.
Thanks. 
Have a nice day.

P.S. Sorry. Here is the code i'm trying to make work. It lists all files from current directory, but do not go to parent directory.
P.S.S My code lists files in current directory and changes to parent directory too. And so on. It work as I expect, but I can't check if current directory is root, and get eternal loop. Thanks.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  DIR *d;
  char cwd[1024];
  struct dirent *dir;
  do {
      d = opendir(".");
       if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
           fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
       else
           perror("getcwd() error");
      if (d)
      {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
          if (dir->d_type == DT_REG)
          {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
          }
        }
        chdir("..");
        closedir(d);
      }
  // Do not know how to check if current directory is root
  // and getting eternal loop 
  }while (cwd != "/");
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Current working dir: /
Current working dir: /
......................
Current working dir: /
```

Comment: Please take some time to ***re-read*** [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Especially re-read [about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Souunds like a homework assignment, have you attempted this at all? Post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Hello, @liam_g. Thanks for your answers. I've added the code i'm trying to make work. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: Yes, @Ashish Ahuja. It's homework and i'm stacked with that.

Comment: @Ashish Ahuja, but i'm not asking to solve my homework, i'm asking to help me deal with specific problem. Code is present. Problem described.

Comment: Not sure why so many downvotes, it's a legitimate question, how to check if you are at the root directory.

Comment: Hello, @Sam Watkins. It's simple. At beginning I just added what I need to realize without code present. And collected some downvotes before added problem code))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cwd[1] != 0` or `cwd[1] != '\0'` is an okay way to do it.  There's no need to cast that to an int.

You could also use `strcmp(cwd, "/")`, which makes it slightly more clear what you are doing.  This will be zero at the root directory on a UNIX or Linux system.

For a more portable solution, you can compare the current directory name with the previous directory name, something like this:

```
char cwd[1024];
char parent[1024];
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
```

and inside the loop:

```
        chdir("..");
        getcwd(parent, sizeof(parent));
        if (strcmp(cwd, parent) == 0)
                break;
        strcpy(cwd, parent);
```

On a POSIX system, you can check if the current directory is the root without using `getcwd()`, using code like this:

```
int cwd_is_root(void)
{
        struct stat cwd, parent;
        if (stat(".", &cwd) < 0)
                return -1;
        if (stat("..", &parent) < 0)
                return -1;
        return cwd.st_ino == parent.st_ino && cwd.st_dev == parent.st_dev;
}
```

It is simpler and better just to use `getcwd` as you did, unless you are writing your own libc!  `getcwd` is a system call on Linux.

Comment: Thanks you, @Sam Watkins. So much additional options. Need to try it to remember and improve my skills. Thanks you again. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, maybe not elegant, but working - check if

```
(int)cwd[1] != 0
```

int value of second element of **cwd** array is **0**. It means the directory is "/" - parent and stops.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  DIR *d;
  char cwd[1024];
  struct dirent *dir;
  do {
      d = opendir(".");
       if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
           fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
       else
           perror("getcwd() error");
      if (d)
      {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
          if (dir->d_type == DT_REG)
          {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
          }
        }
        chdir("..");
        closedir(d);
      }
  }while ((int)cwd[1] != 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't listing directory content. To do it use:

```
system("ls");      //show files in current directory that doesn't begin with "."
system("ls -a");   //show all files in current directory
```

Simple code that lists current and parent

```
system("ls");
chdir("./..");
system("ls");
```

And it's output

```
$ Debug/lf.o
list_files.c                   //current directory
Debug  src  test_file.txt      //parent directory
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mati865. But my code list files in current directory and changes to parent directory too. And so on. It work as I expect, but I can't check if current directory is root, and get eternal loop(( Thanks.